# Constant page recompilation in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, nodemon

I don't know why but my angular application is recompiling again and again without any obvious reason and it's refreshing the page. I guess that the nodemon is activated from time to time, but I cannot understand why. This happens obviously, not only when I save the program like it's need to be.

Has anyone encountered this issue? Should I reinstall angular/CLI? Or maybe reinstall the NODE client?

Comment: Could your ide be autosaving as you type? This would cause the files to change which in turn would cause angular cli to rebuild

Comment: Are you storing your project on a remote drive like Dropbox? Sometimes the Dropbox background processes modify the files and relaunch nodemon or webpack-dev-server.

Comment: the project not on dropbox. and it happen even if i dont touch the computer.